# Не получается разобрать ответ JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Не получается разобрать ответ JSON который получаю с сайта.

Мне нужно вывести из ответа все значения `name`, делаю так:

```
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "response";
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "name";

JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE ); // Массив из историй
            for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)   // Перебор массива историй
            {
               JSONArray history = results.get(i).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
               for(int j = 0; j < history.length(); j++)   // Перебор истории
               {

                  System.out.println("Статья:" + history.get(j));
               }
            }
```

В этом коде Eclipse ругается на строку:

```
JSONArray history = results.get(i).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
```

`The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type Object`

Ответ с сервера:

```
{"id":"13","story":[{"name":"\u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b \u0417\u043e\u043b ","author":"1"}]},
{"id":"12","story":[{"name":"\u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 \u0412\u043e\u0443 ","author":"1"}]},
{"id":"10","story":[{"name":"\u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a \u041c\u0443\u0440\u043b\u044b\u043a ","author":"1"}]}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У results нет метода get(index), надо обращаться сразу results.getJSONArray(index).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать с помощью импорта библиотеки `jackson`:

Создайте класс который будет парсить ваш `Json` например `ParserJson.java` 
который будет содержать :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ParserJson {
    @JsonProperty
    public int id;
    public JsonAnswer[] story;

    public static class AnswerJson {
        @JsonProperty
        public String name;
        @JsonProperty
        public int author;
    }
}
```

Далее там где Вам нужно получить строку из ответа `Json`: делаете так:

```
private void answerInJson(ParserJson.JsonAnswer[] answer ){
        for (ParserJson.JsonAnswer jsonAnswer : answer) {
            System.out.println(jsonAnswer.name);//тут делайте все что нужно с вашим ответом
            System.out.println(jsonAnswer.author);//тут делайте все что нужно с вашим ответом
        }
    }
```

Далее в месте вызова метода `answerInJson`: передайте в него такие параметры:

```
String json = getAnswerInJson();// тут в строку заходит Ваш ответ в формате Json
ParserJson parserJson= objectMapper.readValue(json,ParserJson.class);
answerInJson(parserJson.story);
```

Примерно так Вы сможете полностью распарсить Ваш `Json` и кооректно работать со всеми приходящими данными

Answer (score 0):

```
results.get(i)
```

возвращает Object, приведите тип к JSONArray

```
((JSONArray) results.get(i)).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
```

Comment: теперь в этой же строке такая ошибка  `The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: @Денис, вам очевидно нужен не jsonArray, а jsonObject

Comment: судя по описанию JSONArray умеет искать только по порядковому номеру элемента. а JSONObject умеет по String ключу искать

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должен выглядеть код, судя по структуре json:

```
JSONArray history = results.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
```